# Change the color of selected item - ion-select

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Do you know how to change the color of the selected item on `ion-select`? I have tried many things here but none of them worked. Any clue please?

`Doc:` https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select

I have tried with the `color` property. But it doesn't work. i.e. it always shows the `primary` color.

I want to set `tertiary` here.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
          <ion-select
            mode="md"
            formControlName="sortBy"
            placeholder="Sort By"
            interface="popover"
            color="tertiary" // is not working here
            (ionChange)="sortBy($event)"
          >
            <ion-select-option value="1">Newest</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="2">Oldest</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="3">Near Me</ion-select-option>
            
          </ion-select>
        </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First in your .ts file, you need to create a variable to hold the data for interfaceOptions in which I added the ***customPopoverOptions*** variable.

```
customPopoverOptions: any = {
  cssClass: 'popover-wide',
};
```

In your html file, you need to add the ***interfaceOptions*** to import the cssClass from the *global.scss*:

```
<ion-select mode="md" [interfaceOptions]="customPopoverOptions" placeholder="Sort By" interface="popover">
  <ion-select-option value="1">Newest</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="2">Oldest</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="3">Near Me</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Add the css below in your *global.scss*. The reason that we need to add it in the *global.scss* is that the ion-popover is appended outside of the current page. In Angular, the CSS of a specific page is scoped only to elements of that page.

```
.popover-wide {
  ion-radio {
    --color-checked: red !important;
  }
}
```

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-tabs-boilerplate-j9cybu?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts) for you to check my implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the documentation for the `ion-select-option`.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select-option

```
    /*
    * "my-custom-interface" needs to be passed in through
    * the cssClass of the interface options for this to work
    */
    .my-custom-interface .select-interface-option {
      color: red;
    }
    
    /* Popover Interface: set color for the popover using Item's CSS variables */
   .my-custom-interface .select-interface-option {
      --color: #971e49;
      --color-hover: #79193b;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I have done everything. I was able to change the color of the label. But not the selected option button color. Have you done this kind of task before?

Comment: @Sampath - I am not sure what the selected option button is? Are you attempting to change the color of the selected item from the drop down?

Comment: @Sampath - got it. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have tried this. But this changes only the label color. i.e. not what I need like so on my image above. Any clue?