# How to change radio color on selected ion-select

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ion-select

I created this select [My ion-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHezV.png)

So I changed the color of the buttons to cancel and Ok, so far everything as it should be. My problem is that I can't change the color of the selected radio. the default color is blue, i would like to change the radio color when selected.

```
<ion-select id="category" cancelText="Cancelar" okText="Confirmar" multiple="true" value="" placeholder="Selecionar">
  <ion-select-option color="verde" value="Acessórios para Veículos">Acessórios para Veículos</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="Alimentos e Bebidas">Alimentos e Bebidas</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="Animais">Animais</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="Antiguidades e Coleções">Antiguidades e Coleções</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="Arte e Papelaria ">Arte e Papelaria </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190742/change-the-color-of-selected-item-ion-select

Comment: This method does not seem to apply in my case. Note that my ion-select is multiple

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt the answer to your case :

- In your **html**, add the **[interfaceOptions]** :

  ```
  <ion-select [interfaceOptions]="customAlertOptions" id="category" cancelText="Cancelar" okText="Confirmar" multiple="true" value="" placeholder="Selecionar">
     <ion-select-option color="verde" value="Acessórios para Veículos">Acessórios para Veículos</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="Alimentos e Bebidas">Alimentos e Bebidas</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="Animais">Animais</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="Antiguidades e Coleções">Antiguidades e Coleções</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="Arte e Papelaria ">Arte e Papelaria </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
  ```
- In your **ts file**, add the **CssClass**

  ```
  export class HomePage {

    customAlertOptions: any = {
      cssClass: 'customAlertCss',

    };
     ....
  }
  ```
- In the **global.scss** you add what you need. The console help you find the class to modify most of the  time

  ```
   .customAlertCss {
       [aria-checked=true].sc-ion-alert-md .alert-checkbox-icon.sc-ion-alert-md {
           border-color: red !important;
           background-color: red !important;
    }

  }
  ```

[image: Now it's in red]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: For those looking for the same solution: don't forget to add the mode="md"

Comment: Great, you can valide the answer as the solution then. Happy coding !